# Unable to resolve "C:\Workspace\Angular\allaboutspace-mdb\node_modules" in angular while running using ng serve

Tags: angular, visual-studio

When I try to run my angular app using the following command

```
ng serve --open
```

I am getting below error message in the console. Not sure what went wrong. Any help please. Thanks in advance.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKIoC.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have node_modules already in your app folder, try to remove it then install the packages again using your package manager Yarn/NPM, then try again.

```
yarn install
```

Or

```
npm install
```

Comment: deleting node_modules and then npm install didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then reinstall `npm` which might resolve your issue.

```
remove node_modules 
remove package-lock.json
npm install
```

**EDIT:**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: deleting node_modules and then npm install didnt work for me and also tried reinstalling npm

Comment: Did you remove `package-lock. json` as well?

Comment: Yes removed package-loc.json as well.

Comment: Can you try with the EDIT part?